# React Date and Time Picker in Search Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, datetimepicker

I'm trying to develop booking system for my business website [theluxurytransfers.com](https://theluxurytransfers.com),
[Github Repo:](https://github.com/dusanw/booking-system.git),
[Codesandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/dusanw/booking-system/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3u000a356lyzx35j7x%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3u000c356lx6m9xqwv%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clhkaqf3u000a356lyzx35j7x%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3t0009356lvuxs5qdo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3u000a356lyzx35j7x%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3t0009356lvuxs5qdo%2522%257D%252C%2522clhkaqf3u000c356lx6m9xqwv%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3u000b356ldi4ho9p8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3u000c356lx6m9xqwv%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clhkaqf3u000b356ldi4ho9p8%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)
In order to achieve it I was told to redo my web to react. I'm at the search component where I try do display date and time picker for the customers to choose from, you can find working version in [here](https://theluxurytransfers.com/)
I'm new to react so it's work in progress as I go. I've managed to show search things but date and time is not showing and I have no idea why, code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../css/search.css';
import { FormControlLabel, Radio, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { DesktopDateTimePicker } from '@mui/lab';
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker, TimePicker } from '@mui/lab';


function Search() {
  const [tripType, setTripType] = useState('oneway');
  const [depDateTime, setDepDateTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [retDateTime, setRetDateTime] = useState(new Date());

  const handleTripTypeChange = (event) => {
    setTripType(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="advanced-search color" id="booking">
      <div className="wrap">
        <form action="search-results.html" method="post">
          <div className="f-row">
            <div className="form-group datepicker one-third">
              <label htmlFor="dep-date">Departure date and time</label>
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DatePicker
                  label="Date"
                  value={depDateTime}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setDepDateTime(newValue);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
                <TimePicker
                  label="Time"
                  value={depDateTime}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setDepDateTime(newValue);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>

            </div>
            <div className="form-group select one-third">
                            <label>Pick up location</label>
                            <select>
                                <option selected>&nbsp;</option>
                                <optgroup label="Austria">
                                    <option value="Vienna">Vienna</option>
                                    <option value="Salzburg">Salzburg</option>
                                    <option value="Innsbruck">Innsbruck</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Czech Republic">
                                    <option value="Prague">Prague</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Germany">
                                    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
                                    <option value="Munich">Munich</option>
                                    <option value="Frankfurt">Frankfurt</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Hungary">
                                    <option value="Budapest">Budapest</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Poland">
                                    <option value="Krakow">Krakow</option>
                                    <option value="Warsaw">Warsaw</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group select one-third">
                            <label>Drop off location</label>
                            <select>
                                <option selected>&nbsp;</option>
                                <optgroup label="Austria">
                                    <option value="Vienna">Vienna</option>
                                    <option value="Salzburg">Salzburg</option>
                                    <option value="Innsbruck">Innsbruck</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Czech Republic">
                                    <option value="Prague">Prague</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Germany">
                                    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
                                    <option value="Munich">Munich</option>
                                    <option value="Frankfurt">Frankfurt</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Hungary">
                                    <option value="Budapest">Budapest</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Poland">
                                    <option value="Krakow">Krakow</option>
                                    <option value="Warsaw">Warsaw</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </div>
          </div>

          {tripType === 'return' && (
            <div className="f-row">
              <div className="form-group datepicker one-third">
                <label htmlFor="ret-date">Return date and time</label>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                  <DesktopDateTimePicker
                    id="ret-date"
                    value={retDateTime}
                    onChange={(newValue) => setRetDateTime(newValue)}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group select one-third">
                            <label>Pick up location</label>
                            <select>
                                <option selected>&nbsp;</option>
                                <optgroup label="Austria">
                                    <option value="Vienna">Vienna</option>
                                    <option value="Salzburg">Salzburg</option>
                                    <option value="Innsbruck">Innsbruck</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Czech Republic">
                                    <option value="Prague">Prague</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Germany">
                                    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
                                    <option value="Munich">Munich</option>
                                    <option value="Frankfurt">Frankfurt</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Hungary">
                                    <option value="Budapest">Budapest</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Poland">
                                    <option value="Krakow">Krakow</option>
                                    <option value="Warsaw">Warsaw</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group select one-third">
                            <label>Drop off location</label>
                            <select>
                                <option selected>&nbsp;</option>
                                <optgroup label="Austria">
                                    <option value="Vienna">Vienna</option>
                                    <option value="Salzburg">Salzburg</option>
                                    <option value="Innsbruck">Innsbruck</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Czech Republic">
                                    <option value="Prague">Prague</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Germany">
                                    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
                                    <option value="Munich">Munich</option>
                                    <option value="Frankfurt">Frankfurt</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Hungary">
                                    <option value="Budapest">Budapest</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="Poland">
                                    <option value="Krakow">Krakow</option>
                                    <option value="Warsaw">Warsaw</option>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </div>
            </div>
          )}

          <div className="f-row">
            <div className="form-group spinner">
                            <label for="people">How many people <small>(including children)</small>?</label>
                            <input type="number" id="people" min="1"  />
                        </div>
            <div className="form-group radios">
              <div>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="Return"
                  value="return"
                  checked={tripType === 'return'}
                  onChange={handleTripTypeChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Radio />}
                  label="One way"
                  value="oneway"
                  checked={tripType === 'oneway'}
                  onChange={handleTripTypeChange}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group right">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn large black" id="find-transfer-button">Find a transfer</button>
                        </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

I tried Date picker and Time picker seprately, DesktopDateTimePicker from MUI. I've adjusted css z-indexes to 9999, it was suggested that it causing the picker not to show, but that didnt solved it.